# Calling GC.Collect inside loop and thread and Clearing collection doesn't decrease memory usage

Tags: c#, memory, garbage-collection

I have many objects and each object has many members, I need to insert some collection data into each members and clearing them again after using them.. after I clear it I hope  GC.Collect() can claim Memory usage immediately , but its look doesn't decrease memory usage.. I've check on task manager is always increasing. Only after all processing task complete I notice the memory usage was down.

The memory usage achieve up to 10G achive almost 100% on my PC.. and the usage only going down after all the processing done.. I afraid if client pc memory is not enough then will cause the outofmemory exception

and I notice Clearing all collection data doesn't looks like reduce the memory usage..
How I should claim the memory back ?

and is it will be ok calling GC.Collect inside the loop inside the thread ?

Illustration looks like this. 
ex :

```
public class Progress 
{
   var obj2 = new Obj2();

   public void Processing()
   {
       //here my thread start.. (I have some thread class)
       AsyncClass.DoTask(() =>
       {
           foreach(var curProcess in AllObjects)
           {

             var allSolutions = (from m in curProcess.memories
                               where.... 
                               select m).ToList();

            forearch(var memory in allSolutions)
            {  
               foreach(data in alldata)
               {
                 //some process
                 ...
                 ...
                 result = data.result;

                 //pushing the data into memory members obj
                  obj2.PushCalculation(memory, result)
               }
             }

            forearch(var memory in allSolutions)
            {  
                obj2.ClearValues(memory)
            }

             GC.Collect();
             GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
         }
      });
    }
  }

  public class Obj2 : IDisposable
  {
    public void PushCalculation(memoryObj mem, List<data> results)
    {
       foreach(var result in results)
       {
          mem.data1.add(result);
          mem.data2.addrange(result * 1);
            //etc... all about pushing into memory object members
       }
    }

    public void ClearValues(memoryObj mem)
    {
       // clear all collections of memoryObj members 

       mem.data1.Clear();
       mem.data1 = null;

       mem.data2.Clear();
       mem.data2 = null;

       ...... 
       ......
    }

  }
```

Comment: Are you disposing those objects since they are disposable?

Comment: The fact that memory usage doesn't go down until your processing completes tells me that there is no garbage to collect. Garbage collection is not a magical "shrink my memory usage" function.

Comment: @Raymond Chen, is it clearing the dynamic collection doesn't free up some memory usage ?

Comment: Garbage collection cannot free memory that is still reachable. That would result in crashes.

Comment: And besides, there is no reason to suppose that any of the memory statistics reported by task manager bear any relation to the size of the managed heap. Most people do not understand what the "memory size" reported in task manager even means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: you should let the *garbage collector* (GC) do its job. It can probably judge when to collect garbage a lot better than you, based on the system, current load, application profile and other factors.

Second: the garbage collector allocates some memory space to operate in. This space may not shrink even though the collector correctly collected most of it. It is then empty, but available for future allocations; or it may shrink at a later point in time.

But if the garbage collector is actually unable to collect some of your objects, then you still have references to those objects somewhere. Perhaps in a static fields, or a collection you forgot about?

What you should take from this is: *never* call `GC.Collect()`. There are only very few good reasons to call `GC.Collect()`. If you have some memory issue that prompted you to use `GC.Collect()` then you should instead be investigating what's causing the memory issue.

Possible causes that I can think of from the top of my head:

- Keeping a reference to an object that you no longer need.
- Using an unmanaged resource and afterwards not disposing it properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I agree, actually I not plan to call GC.Collect at firsttime.. but just because I curious why the memory can't claim back immediately, i notice only one event delegate but i already detach them actively, event before clearing the values "-=" ...  and there no unmanage resource being used..  just notice clearing values into the collection doesn't mean reducing memory usage ?..

Answer (score 1):

Your code is probably not real but I will try to answer anyway.

When you call `PushCalculation`, you add pointers to objects of `data` class (assuming `data` is not a struct) to the `mem.data1`, `mem.data2` collections. So after that operation you have two references to each data object. One goes from `mem.data` and the other is from `data.results`.

Then in `ClearValues` you clear one of the references from each `data` object but `results` still pins them all. You need to clear `data.results` too if you want the garbage collector to free the memory.

In other words you have a memory leak. See this answer on how to investigate memory leaks.
[How to debug the potential memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517288/how-to-debug-the-potential-memory-leak)
I personally used WinDbg and found it extremely useful. It shows what pins down an object in memory

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collectors are complex beasts and the simplicity of the interface to them is deceiving. Just call `GC.Collect()`, right?

The .NET garbage collector is a generational GC. When it runs, it looks for *new* objects to get rid of first. This comes from the idea that the overwhelming majority of objects are short-lived. Objects that survived are placed into a different memory pool and this pool isn't scanned as often. If I remember correctly, there are three such pools. This means that when the GC does a run, it does not scan the whole heap.

Also note that those are *pools*. This means that when the virtual machine wants to allocate memory, it looks in the pool for free memory before trying to expand the heap. This is only possible if the memory of collected objects is not immediately reclaimed. In other words, when the GC collects an object, it doesn't necessarily return the memory to the operating system.

Which leads us to `GC.Collect()`. We know that when the GC runs, it doesn't scan the whole heap, and when it destroys objects, it doesn't return memory. Then, what's the point of calling `GC.Collect()`? I can't answer that one. As far as I'm concerned, calling `GC.Collect()` isn't useful.